# For ADAL.js (or MSAL) with ReactJS/AngularJS, what's best way to handle versioning the framework

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, versioning, adal.js, msal.js

I’m working with a large company with multiple dispersed teams developing applications using the ADAL client libraries and either the React and/or Angular frameworks. Over time, the **various organizations within the company have each modified/extended ADAL.js to create their own adaptations** for handling different needs (for example, implementations differences for React vs Angular …or handling different versions of a framework, like Angular 2 vs Angular 5).

With this context in mind, I was asked the specific question:

> "Just wanted to know if Microsoft has any plans to enhance and support 
>   ADAL.js for newer frameworks as most UI use cases for Azure AD would be on Angular and React and these ‘solutions’ are frequently updated"

- In other words, do we have guidance (and/or a roadmap) for a more abstracted way of handling the implementation with various frameworks …or across different versions of a particular framework?
- Or should each org continue to create their own adaptations?

Answer (score 0):

So far there appears to be updates to existing ADAL libraries but no plans to support additional web frameworks.  I.e "to bad so sad" for those of us using Angular 2/4/5/6

See the following issues in the ADAL.js github repo

- [azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/510](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/510)
- [azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/379](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/379)

Also keep an eye here:  [Vittorio Bertocci's Blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/?s=ADAL)

There are a bunch of 3rd party efforts to create wrappers for later versions of angular, but they all need to be vetted before use (that is certainly what I am doing).

Answer (score 0):

We do have plans for building wrapper libraries for Angular in the Azure AD SDK roadmap. However, we are focusing the efforts on the newer [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) library which integrates with the [Azure AD v2](https://aka.ms/aadv2) endpoint and brings additional capabilities such as support for Azure AD B2C and signing in MSA accounts. You can track this [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/77) on the MSAL.js repo.